# Unable to launch the real device(iPhone & iPad) session in Mac machine

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, appium-ios

I have been trying to setup the environment in Mac to execute the automation scripts in real device using Appium 1.6.4 version.

Our project is build with Selenium-java.try to executing the scripts using selenium grid.

I have done the environment setup in the Mac machine by following the steps in this link : http://toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/appium-test-on-real-ios-device/

```
ios_webkit_debug_proxy -c <Connected device UDID>:27753 –d
```

When I'm trying to execute the above command in terminal I'm getting the following error :

```
Could not connect to lockdownd. Exiting.: Permission denied
ss.remove_server_fd(4)
Unable to attach 5d59aeb93f96b07f94a4ac7c1e860c891d9493d9 inspector
```

Can anyone please help on this? or Is there any better way to done the iOS real device setup in mach machine?

Comment: Did you did this? Connect your iOS device to your machine via USB cable. On your device, open the Settings app. Select Safari, scroll down to the bottom of the page and open the Advanced menu. Enable the Web Inspector option.

Comment: yes i did the same. Even though i'm getting this issue @santhoshkumar

Comment: Can you try this brew commands....brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew link --overwrite libimobiledevice
brew install ideviceinstaller
brew link --overwrite ideviceinstaller

Comment: @santhoshkumar : done the above setup & all these things now getting error :   `An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Sdk '10.3.1' was not in list of simctl sdks (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

Comment: have you specified the udid of the real deice in device capabilities @Gowri. Else if you are using simulator, make sure the version you are mentioning in the capabilities is available in your system or just use the version that is available in the system.

Comment: yes @santhoshkumar. I mentioned the udid of the device in desired capabilities.Im using the _10.3.1_ mobile platform version. 

My iPhone 7(version 10.3.1) is connected to the Mac machine.
Connected real device listed under the `instruments -s devices` 

But the device is not displayed under the "xcrun simctl list"

Can someone please advise on what is the actual issue ?

Comment: Are you using lastest xcode?.... Try running using any simulator also

Comment: yes I'm using the latest xcode only . Xcode version : 8.3.2. For simulator is executing well

Comment: @Gowri https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/ios-webkit-debug-proxy.md  - This will help you. Now the Appium provides the capability to start  ios_webkit_debug_proxy automatically. could you give a try.   Set 'startIWDP' is true in you desired capabilities.